# Validation in setter using EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework. I have created an object Registration with a property "AmmountOfChildren" with max set to 50. I want to validate in the setter to make sure that the max ammount is 50. How do i go about it in the best way?

```
  public global::System.Int16 AmmountOfChildren
    {
        get
        {
            return _AmmountOfChildren;
        }
        set
        {
            OnAmmountOfChildrenChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("AmmountOfChildren");
            _AmmountOfChildren = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("AmmountOfChildren");
            OnAmmountOfChildrenChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put a System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute on the property:

```
[Range(0, 50)]
public global::System.Int16 AmmountOfChildren
```

This will cause the property to be validated when SaveChanges is called.